Namespace error when printing array using method
I'm trying to print the array called puzzle. However, I get this error:

Error CS8803: Top-level statements must precede namespace and type declarations.

This happens when trying to use prettySudoku() on the last line. I am running this using dotnet and the linux/ubuntu terminal. This is my first time using methods.
Here's the code:
int[] list1 = new int[]{7, 3, 6, 4, 5, 2, 9, 8, 1};
    int[] list2 = new int[]{1, 9, 8, 6, 3, 7, 4, 5, 2};
    int[] list3 = new int[]{4, 2, 5, 9, 8, 1, 3, 7, 6};
    int[] list4 = new int[]{3, 6, 4, 5, 2, 8, 1, 9, 7};
    int[] list5 = new int[]{9, 5, 2, 7, 1, 4, 6, 3, 8};
    int[] list6 = new int[]{8, 1, 7, 3, 9, 6, 2, 4, 5};
    int[] list7 = new int[]{2, 8, 9, 1, 7, 3, 5, 6, 4};
    int[] list8 = new int[]{6, 7, 3, 2, 4, 5, 8, 1, 9};
    int[] list9 = new int[]{5, 4, 1, 8, 6, 9, 7, 2, 3};

int[][] puzzle = new int[][] {list1, list2, list3, list4, list5, list6, list7, list8, list9};

public class prettyPrinters{

    public void prettySudoku(int[][] arr){

        for(int i = 0; i<arr.GetLength(0); i++){

            for(int j =0; j<arr.GetLength(1); j++){
                Console.WriteLine(arr[i][j]);
            }
        }
    }
}

prettySudoku(puzzle);


You defined prettySudoku as member of the prettyPrinters class. so you need an instance of that class to call a member of that class. One way calling it would be new prettyPrinters().prettySudoku(puzzle);

The error statement is pretty clear, Top-level statements (prettySudoku(puzzle);) must precede namespace (int [][] line) and type declarations public class prettyPrinters).
This is the general program structure of all variants of C (C++, C# etc. ) languages.
So, you should move up declaration line prettySudoku(puzzle);. To avoid repetition, read here for more details.
